# Internetinformation service does not play libvlc http stream

Tags: iis, html5-audio, http-live-streaming

I have created a http stream with libvlc. See the following code:

```
LibVLC libVLC;
MediaPlayer mp;
libVLC = new LibVLC();
mp = new MediaPlayer(libVLC);
mp.TimeChanged += Mp_TimeChanged;
Media media = new Media(libVLC, new Uri("http://listen.technobase.fm/tunein-aac-hd-pls"));
        media.AddOption(":sout=#transcode{vcodec=none,acodec=mp3,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100,scodec=none}:http{dst=:8080/stream.mp3}");
media.AddOption(":sout-keep");
media.AddOption(":no-sout-all");
mp.Play(media);
```

If I use a html file with the follwing code the stream is working fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <audio controls="controls" runat="server" autoplay="autoplay">
        <source src="http://innoszorn.ddnss.de:8080/stream.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
        Your Browser does not support this stream!
    </audio>
</body>
</html>
```

But if I use this file as an embedded file on my IIS server with Windows Server 2019 the stream doesn't start. The Mime type installed is on the IIS and it's exact the same code.
Is there any additional option I have to activate in the IIS to start the stream?

Comment: I haven't used the libvlc class library. Can you play the audio through the console project? IIS may not support hosting such kind of project.
Please refer to the below project.
https://github.com/leixiaohua1020/simplest_libvlc_example/blob/master/simplest_libvlc_player/simplest_libvlc_player.cpp

Comment: It works if you use the src adress direct in the broswer. The stream open and it's fine. So the stream is working. But it's just not working with IIS. In the development environment it's working fine. But after the distribution to the server it's not working anymore.

Comment: I knew that it works properly since HTML5 has already supported this kind of file and this MIME type has been registered in IIS. I mean that how do you play it by using the liblvc library in your project? Did this project supported by IIS? I am afraid of not.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. No it's a seperate project. The libvlc project just create the HTML stream for the HTML5 player.